# How do I send a drupal_http_request() with GET method?

Tags: http-request

Following examples found here and in API, I tried 2 methods, both return a **bad request** status message.

### First method

```
$data = 'name=value&name1=value1';

$options = array(
  'method' => 'GET',
  'data' => $data,
  'timeout' => 15,
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
);

$result = drupal_http_request('http://example.com/foo', $options);

dpm($result);
```

### Second method

```
$data = array(
  'key1' => $value1,
  'key2' => $value2,
);

$full_url = url('http://example.com/foo', array('query' => $data));

$options = array(
  'method' => 'GET',
  'timeout' => 15,
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
);
$result = drupal_http_request($full_url, $options);

dpm($result);
```

Which one is the good one and what's wrong ? Thank you

### Edit

This is `dpm($result)`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method is correct; you should not use [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7.x) for an external URL that is passed to `drupal_http_request()`, except (for example) when you want other modules to alter the hook via their [`hook_url_outbound_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7.x) implementations, or you want to let `url()` split off the fragment (or the query) from the URL. (The fragment is used to set `$options['fragment'], when it's not already set; the query is added to` $options['query'].

The code run by `url()` for an external URL is the following one. (I showed only the relevant code; where I omitted code, I used an `// Omissis` comment. I also removed the original comments from the code and added mine to evidence some code parts.)

```php
if (!isset($options['external'])) {
  $options['external'] = $path === $_GET['q'] ? FALSE : url_is_external($path);
}

// Omissis

if ($options['external']) {
  if (strpos($path, '#') !== FALSE) {
    list($path, $old_fragment) = explode('#', $path, 2);
    if (isset($old_fragment) && !$options['fragment']) {
      $options['fragment'] = '#' . $old_fragment;
    }
  }

  if ($options['query']) {
    $path .= (strpos($path, '?') !== FALSE ? '&' : '?') . drupal_http_build_query($options['query']);
  }

  // Change the URL protocol basing on a Drupal local setting.
  if (isset($options['https']) && variable_get('https', FALSE)) {
    if ($options['https'] === TRUE) {
      $path = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $path);
    }
    elseif ($options['https'] === FALSE) {
      $path = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $path);
    }
  }

  return $path . $options['fragment'];
}
```

Apart from what I reported before, there isn't much any pro in using `url()` when used for a string you already know it contains an external URL. The part commented with `Change the URL protocol basing on a Drupal local setting.` only changes the used protocol basing on the value of `$options['https']`, when a local Drupal settings has been set to `TRUE`. For a string that contains already an external URL, which is then passed to `drupal_http_request()`, that code isn't much helpful; you would know already if the external URL needs to be accessed via https:// or http://, and you would not want to change the used protocol basing on a local setting.

*application/x-www-form-urlencoded* is the content type used when POSTing data, while you are GETting data.

To build the query data, you could also use [`drupal_http_build_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_build_query/7), which the same function used from `url()` for the same purpose.

```
$data = array('name' => 'value', 'name1' => 'value1');

$options = array(
  'method' => 'GET',
  'data' => drupal_http_build_query($data),
  'timeout' => 15,
);

$result = drupal_http_request('http://example.com/foo', $options);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added `dpm($result)` in the question. So if this is correct, does the bad request means that the code is ok, but the target website was expecting another query  ?

Comment: _Bad request_ means the server cannot understand the request, which could simply be because you are setting the content type that is expected from a POST, or because you are passing the wrong data for http://example.com/foo. I would think it is the first case.

Comment: All rights, I'll check better the remote expected configuration. Grazie mile per il suo tempo  ;)

Comment: The second method is correct if you're wanting to pass the data as query parameters: `$full_url = url('http://example.com/foo', array('query' => $data));`

The 'data' option only refers to the body of the request, not the query parameters. See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7.x